# How do you insert 3 items into a multimap

Tags: c++

I am trying to enter three items into a multimap.
-Title
-Genre
-Rating
Is there a way to insert two strings and int value into a multimap. And how would I print out this multi map?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    multimap<string, string, int> hi;
    string title, gerne;
    int rating; 

    cout << "Please enter a title gerne and rating or exit the loop by pressing "".""" << endl;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Title:";
        cin >> title;

        cout << endl << "Genre:";
        cin >> gerne;

        cout <<endl<< "Rating:"; 
        cin >> rating;

        hi.insert(pair<string, string, int>(title, gerne, rating));

        if (title == ".")
            break;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted `multimap<string, pair<string, int>>` or perhaps `map<string, pair<string, int>>` if you don't have multiple items that have the same title

Comment: better yet, why not make a new class/object which contains all of this data, then just use a simple dictionary/map (with some identifier as the key). That way you don't end up with maps inside maps, or multiple maps.

Comment: the "multi" in `multimap` is not about multiple dimensions as your code seems to assume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map` and `std::multimap` is a key -> value storage, which means there is a single key and single value. It does not mean you cannot keep multiple data types, but you have to wrap them into single value like structure. For example:

```
using mmap = std::multimap< std::string, std::pair<std::string,int> >;
```

Which means there is a key `std::string` as I assume you have in title and then genre and rating as value. This structure means that data will be sorted by title only. If you need genre to be part of sort key as well then you need to make key a pair instead:

```
using mmap = std::multimap< std::pair<std::string, std::string> ,int> >;
```

Note it will be sorted by title and then by genre. If you need to search by title or genre or rating individually, then `std::multimap` is not an appropriate data type for you and you may need to look into [`boost::multiindex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) or organize multiple indexes manually.